# Copy and paste articles/namespaces

Tags: mysql, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

This might be a far fetched question, but here it goes:
I'm trying to configure a MediaWiki and I'm grouping content into namespaces. I need to find a reasonably easy way for copying a namespace (including content) and pasting it with a different name. First of all: is this possible? Are there any extensions for this? I've looked a bit at the MediaWiki database and I can implement my own software if it is needed, but there are a lot of tables, so if you can give any guidelines it would be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was easily solved. Just export everything by using Special:Export (Special:AllPages can filter by namespace). You can then parse the exported file and change for instance the content between each `<title>` tag to whatever you want. For example the name of the namespace or subpage you want to transfer the content to.

When you're done you just import it back by using Special:Import.